# How to run all gtest files at once using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I have several .cpp files that contain tests for different classes and look like this:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace {
//lots of tests
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

and a CMakeLists.txt file that looks like this:

```
add_subdirectory(/usr/src/gtest gtest)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(TestA TestA.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestA
     gtest
)

add_executable(TestB TestB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestB
    gtest
)

add_executable(TestC TestC.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestC
    gtest
)
```

I like this setup because it's handy to run just the tests for the component I am currently working on. Executing one Test file is obviously much faster than executing all of them. However, every now and then I want to run all tests. How can I achieve this easily within my setup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [CTest](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/ctest.html) (it's usually installed along with CMake) to achieve this.

First, you need to `include` the [CTest module](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/module/CTest.html) in your CMakeLists.txt, then you just need to use the [`add_test`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/add_test.html) command for each of your test executables:

```
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(/usr/src/gtest gtest)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(TestA TestA.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestA gtest)
add_test(NAME AllTestsInA COMMAND TestA)

add_executable(TestB TestB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestB gtest)
add_test(NAME AllTestsInB COMMAND TestB)

add_executable(TestC TestC.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestC gtest)
add_test(NAME AllTestsInC COMMAND TestC)
```

Now, once your test exes are built, from your build folder you can execute CTest to run all the tests.  E.g. to run the Debug tests:

```
ctest -C Debug
```

or to get more verbose output:

```
ctest -C Debug -V
```