# How to execute all gtests for a cmake project with qtcreator?

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, googletest

(As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378549/how-to-run-all-gtest-files-at-once-using-cmake))

My cmake file looks like this:

```
include(CTest)
add_subdirectory(/usr/src/gtest gtest)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(TestA TestA.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestA gtest)
add_test(NAME AllTestsInA COMMAND TestA)

add_executable(TestB TestB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(TestB gtest)
add_test(NAME AllTestsInB COMMAND TestB)
```

I am able to run single tests from within qtcreator and all tests from command line using `ctest --output-on-failure`, but how can I execute all tests from within qtcreator?

qtcreator version: 2.7.0

Answer (score 2):

You should have a target called just `test`.  If you build this, it executes all the tests.

For non-makefile IDEs (like Visual Studio) the equivalent target is called `RUN_TESTS`.

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Raring, clang++ 3.3.3

Comment: yes. BUT: I execute cmake in build/, so that source and binaries don't mix up. I have a GNUMakefile in the project root with a target test, which basically cd's into build/ and calls ctest there. This also works from the command line, but might be a problem for QtCreator?

Comment: Yes - could be.  I've been using QtCreator on OSX recently (with Clang), and I just checked that the `test` target works as expected there.  It's definitely a good plan to keep your sources and binaries in different directories.  You could try replacing the root GNUMakefile with a shell script I guess?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your last sentence...a shell script doing what? I can execute all the tests by running `make test` in the project root, which will in turn cd into build/ to run `ctest` from there. I just want to run it from within QtCreator

Comment: I thought the Makefile in your project root was something you had hand-coded or which predated your use of CMake in this project.  If there's a CMake-generated Makefile in your project's root (rather than "build/"), then CMake has been run from your root dir.

Comment: I do not even get a test target. Using the latest creator (3.5.1) on linux and building off source. had to add configuration in run section to call ctest.

Answer (score 2):

Using QtCreator 2.4.1, try adding a custom build step:
Projects -> "Build Steps" -> [Add Build Step].
[x] Enable this step and use "ctest" as the command.